# Python3 Annotation Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

when I use python3 annotation

```
class UserBean(SerializationBean):

    # serial_field = {"account", "nick_name"}
    non_serial_field = {"password"}

    def __init__(self, account: str = None, password: str = None, nick_name: str = None, roommate: UserBean = None):
        super().__init__()
        self._account = account
        self._password = password
        self._nick_name = nick_name
        self._roommate = roommate
```

The roommate's annotation will raise NameError: name 'UserBean' is not defined
How to resolve it?

Comment: Put it in quotes. `roommate: 'UserBean'`

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Ensure this is not related to your problem.